# Concatenating const_string's

Tags: c++, boost, immutability, string-concatenation, expression-templates

How do I concatenate two `const_string`'s? Its home http://conststring.sourceforge.net/ says citation:

*It also uses expression templates for concatenation, effectively eliminating overhead resulting from creation intermediate temporary objects.*

So I thought its simplest form

```
typedef class boost::const_string<char> csc;
csc a, b;
csc c = a+b;
```

should work. But gcc-4.6 complains about operator+. Why? Do I have to cast `a` and `b` to `std::string`?

Error output follows:

```
semnet/realfile.cpp:185:13: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘a + b’
semnet/realfile.cpp:185:13: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note: std::_Bit_const_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_const_iterator&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘csc’ to ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note: std::_Bit_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_iterator&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘csc’ to ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2414:20: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2408:27: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2402:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2396:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const _CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2384:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2378:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2372:58: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2359:79: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2344:26: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:710:79: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:695:58: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2307:58: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1113:43: note: template<class _Iterator> std::move_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::move_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:328:46: note: template<class _Iterator> std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:897:64: note: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> __gnu_cxx::operator+(typename __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::difference_type, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
semnet/realfile.cpp:186:63: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘xns + boost::const_string<char>(boost::cref [with T = const char*]((* & chashid_get_name_static(hid))), 4294967295u)’
semnet/realfile.cpp:186:63: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note: std::_Bit_const_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_const_iterator&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const csc’ to ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note: std::_Bit_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_iterator&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const csc’ to ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2414:20: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2408:27: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2402:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2396:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const _CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2384:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2378:53: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2372:58: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2359:79: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2344:26: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:710:79: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:695:58: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2307:58: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1113:43: note: template<class _Iterator> std::move_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::move_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:328:46: note: template<class _Iterator> std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:897:64: note: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> __gnu_cxx::operator+(typename __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::difference_type, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
semnet/realfile.cpp:187:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make: *** [semnet/realfile.o] Fel 1

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Fri Apr 29 15:42:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you include the relevant header, `boost/const_string/concatenation.hpp`?

Comment: That could perhaps have been a comment :)

Comment: @sehe Really? It’s the answer, isn’t it? I could have formulated it as an answer rather than a question …

Comment: Oh shute. I missed the sting in the tail (concatenation.hpp) :)

Comment: Ahhh, I should of that. I'm gonna include all headers---const_string.hpp, concatenation.hpp, format.hpp and io.hpp for now. They aren't that big. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `const_string` class contains a constructor for concatenations:

```
template<class T, class U>
const_string(concatenation<const_string, T, U> const& expr) // throw(std::bad_alloc, std::length_error)
    : storage_type(0, expr.size())
{
    expr.copy_result_to(const_cast<char_type*>(this->begin()));
}
```

and the library itself contains a `concatenation` class that takes two `const_strings`.

You could use those.

The header in  which the `concatenation` class is defined is also where `operator+` is defined, btw.

Comment: “You should use those” – no. The whole point of the expression templates is that you *don’t* need to use that class directly (unless you want to store the intermediate result). You can safely use `operator +`.